# Ember data mapping

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using the latest version of ember-data (rev. 11) and the REST adapter to pull data from my API. A sample of the returned JSON looks like this:

```
{ 
    "events": [
        {
            "id": "5118dd8c4c80866ef2000051",
            "title": null,
            "starts_at": 1361901600,
            "ends_at": null,
            "currency": "SEK",
            "cents_door": 4000,
            "cents_advance": null,
            "price_door": "40.00 kr",
            "price_advance": null,
            "age_limit": null,
            "venue_section": "PLAYHOUSE",
            "description": null,
            "url": null,
            "repeats": null,
            "repeats_until": null,
            "venue_id": "nefertiti-jazz-club",
            "act_ids": [ "marias-playhouse" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The model looks like this:

```
App.Event = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
  startsAt: DS.attr('number')
  endsAt: DS.attr('number')
  currency: DS.attr('string')
  centsDoor: DS.attr('number')
  centsAdvance: DS.attr('number')
  priceDoor: DS.attr('string')
  priceAdvance: DS.attr('string')
  ageLimit: DS.attr('string')
  venueSection: DS.attr('string')
  description: DS.attr('string')
  url: DS.attr('string')
  repeats: DS.attr('string')
  repeatsUntil: DS.attr('string')
  venue: DS.belongsTo('App.Venue')
  acts: DS.hasMany('App.Act')
```

But when requesting the data, the request completes successfully, but I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the
>   key events but you have no mapping for it

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

===

UPDATE: As requested I'm adding a bit more of my Ember.js app.

My RESTAdapter setup:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform 'raw',
  deserialize: (serialized) ->
    serialized
  serialize: (deserialized) ->
    deserialized

App.Store = DS.Store.extend
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create
    url: LJ.CONFIG.api.url
  revision: 11
```

And routes:

```
App.Router.map ->
  this.resource 'events', ->
    this.route 'new'
  this.resource 'event', path: '/events/:event_id', ->
    this.route 'edit'
  this.resource 'venue', path: '/venues/:venue_id', ->
    this.route 'edit'
    this.resource 'events'
  this.resource 'act', path: '/acts/:act_id', ->
    this.route 'edit'
    this.resource 'events'
  this.route 'search', path: '/search/:term'
  this.route 'doc', path: '/docs/:doc'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much debugging and searching, it seems Ember.js does not support query string parameters yet. I had to instead hack up my routes like this:

```
App.Router.map ->
  this.resource 'events', path: '/events/:country/:region/:city'
  this.route 'eventsNew', path: '/events/new'
  this.resource 'event', path: '/events/:event_id', ->
    this.route 'edit'
  this.resource 'venue', path: '/venues/:venue_id', ->
    this.route 'edit'
    this.resource 'events'
  this.resource 'act', path: '/acts/:act_id', ->
    this.route 'edit'
    this.resource 'events'
  this.route 'search', path: '/search/:term'
  this.route 'doc', path: '/docs/:doc'
```

This is far from perfect, but it works for now. Apparently query string support is slated for a near future release.

Comment: wat? Could you possibly correct syntax and explain further? Also is this still relevant?

Answer (score 1):

The response looks perfect on first glance.

My guess is that you are sending the wrong format for the wrong request.

This format is valid for many `events`, which means a `findAll` or a `findQuery` (`GET /events`)

However, you might get this error if you are returning this response for a single `find` (`GET /events/5118dd8c4c80866ef2000051`)

In that case (when you are fetching only one `event`), your response should look like this:

```
{
  "event": {
    "id": "5118dd8c4c80866ef2000051",
    "title": null,
    // ... rest of attributes
  }
}
```

Comment: It is the correct format. Multiple events are returned under the "events" key, and only a single event is returned under the "event" key. Ember and ember-data work fine for a single event. It's just on this route with multiple events, it's throwing this error.

Comment: What is the URL of the request that is returning the above response?

Comment: It's not public yet, but the URL looks like: `http://lj-web.dev/#/events/?location=goteborg-vastra-gotaland-county-sweden&origin=57.70412399999999%2C11.9788316`. The correct API response is returned, but ember-data just seems to not like it...

Comment: The response format is very much related to the request, that's why I'm asking about the request... U make the request with `App.Event.find({..})` ?

Comment: I'm just using default Ember behavior for this. I haven't written any specific code for this. Should I?

Comment: This is strange. Do you mind editing your answer to show more code and include what causes the request? your routes, etc...

Comment: Also it seems it may have something to do with the query string params. If I remove them, the error goes away...